# Class attribute - Delete a Dictionary from a List

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, class-attributes

I'm trying to write code for users to be able to delete entries previously added. The current list looks as such:

```
[{"_Item__id": 1,"item_name": "MAC PowerBook", "item_type": "Computer", "date_add": "01/06/2020", "dom": "16/02/2000", "item_info": "description of product"}, 
{"_Item__id": 2,"item_name": "Nokia 6210", "item_type": "Phone", "date_add": "01/06/2020", "dom": "01/02/2000", "item_info": "description of product"},  
{"_Item__id": 3, "item_name": "Kodak Retina", "item_type": "Camera", "date_add": "04/06/2020", "dom": "20/12/1931", "item_info": "description of product"}]
```

Tried using the following code:

```
def delete_item():
    print("{0:3}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format("ID", "Item", "Date added", "Date manufactured"))
    for i in Item.py_collection_list:
        print("{0:03d}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format(i.get_id(), i.item_name, i.date_add, i.dom))
        remove_item = input('Type name of the item you would like to delete from collection> ')
        if remove_item == "item_name":
            Item.py_collection_list[{"item_name"}].remove()
```

And got redirected to the main menu.

Tried this code:

```
def delete_item():
    print("{0:3}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format("ID", "Item", "Date added", "Date manufactured"))
    for i in Item.py_collection_list:
        print("{0:03d}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format(i.get_id(), i.item_name, i.date_add, i.dom))
        remove_item = input('Type name of the item you would like to delete from collection> ')
        if remove_item == i.item_name:
            for item in Item.py_collection_list[:]:
                if item['remove_item'] <= 0:
                    Item.py_collection_list.remove(item)
```

And got this error:

```
TypeError: 'Item' object is not subscriptable
```

Tried this code:

```
def delete_item():
    print("{0:3}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format("ID", "Item", "Date added", "Date manufactured"))
    for i in Item.py_collection_list:
        print("{0:03d}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format(i.get_id(), i.item_name, i.date_add, i.dom))
        remove_item = input('Type name of the item you would like to delete from collection> ')
        if remove_item == i.item_name:
            Item.py_collection_list.remove(remove_item)
```

And got this error:

```
Item.py_collection_list.remove(remove_item)
```

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Tried this code:

```
def delete_item():
    print("{0:3}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format("ID", "Item", "Date added", "Date manufactured"))
    for i in Item.py_collection_list:
        print("{0:03d}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format(i.get_id(), i.item_name, i.date_add, i.dom))
        remove_item = input('Type name of the item you would like to delete from collection> ')
        for i in range(len(Item.py_collection_list)):
            if Item.py_collection_list[i]["item_name"] == remove_item:
                del Item.py_collection_list[i]
```

And got this error:

```
if Item.py_collection_list[i]["item_name"] == remove_item:
```

TypeError: 'Item' object is not subscriptable

Tried this code:

```
def delete_item():
    print("{0:3}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format("ID", "Item", "Date added", "Date manufactured"))
    for i in Item.py_collection_list:
        print("{0:03d}\t{1:20}\t{2:10}\t{3:10}".format(i.get_id(), i.item_name, i.date_add, i.dom))
        remove_item = input('Type name of the item you would like to delete from collection> ')
        if remove_item in Item.py_collection_list:
            del Item.py_collection_list[i.item_name]
            return True
        return False
```

Got redirected to the main menu

It seems to be a pretty straight forward option to create but I seem to be completely overseeing the option.

Comment: What is ``Item``? What do you mean by "got redirected to the main menu"? What main menu?

Comment: Item is a class and the list is a variable - https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide . The code above does not give off an errors, just returns me to the main menu of the programme that i'm trying to construct.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest printing the dictionaries first separately i.e., if you want to provide the users the list of available items, before asking for input to delete the item.

Next you could take the input outside the loop something like this.

```py
remove_item = input("Type name of the item you would like to delete from collection:")
for i in Item.py_collection_list:
   if remove_item == i.item_name:
      Item.py_collection_list.remove(i)
```

This deletes the object corresponding to the item from the list .

If your want to delete the 'item_name' attribute of the item object use the following.

```py
remove_item = input("Type name of the item you would like to delete from collection:")
for i in Item.py_collection_list:
   if remove_item == i.item_name:
      delattr(i, "item_name")
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look into this. Unfortunately I seem to get this error:     if remove_item == i['item_name']:
TypeError: 'Item' object is not subscriptable

Comment: This delete_item function you are writing, is it a class module?

Comment: This link explains how to properly access the class variable https://www.toptal.com/python/python-class-attributes-an-overly-thorough-guide

Comment: Yes Item is a class and py_collection_list is the list that stores the data, as the article describes: class Item:
    py_collection_list = []

    def __init__(self, item_name, item_type, date_add, dom, item_info):
        self.__id = Item.get_next_id()
        self.item_name = item_name
        self.item_type = item_type
        self.date_add = date_add
        self.dom = dom
        self.item_info = item_info
        Item.py_collection_list.append(self)

Comment: looking at this code, "Item.py_collection_list"  is not list of dictionary of items. but list of class objects since you are appending "self" to the list. you would have to access it by "i.item_name" in the for loop. I have updated the answer.

Comment: I received this error: AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'item_name'